# Migrating to laravel breaks password field on users table which used to be 32 characters long

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Laravel requires atleast 60 characters for the password field in the users table.

Our old schema had it at 32 characters and all existing passwords in prod are 32 characters or less after enryption.

After we migrate the DB field to 60 characters, the old passwords can not be authenticated if we swtich to laravel.

We can definitely prompt the user to reset their password, but we have to be able to authenticate them first. Which is a problem.

How do we handle this? Looking for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your old system and laravel are using a different hashing method.

If your old system had 32 characters, it could probably be md5 hashing.

To convert your old users to laravel's hashing, you will first have to login the user using their old passwords. When logging in, you have to use your old hashing system (md5 or whatever, along with the salt if any). After user has successfully logged in using that old hashing system, then you ask them to reset their password. Now when you reset their old password, use Larvel's hashing system `Hash::make()`

You could follow the below steps:

1. Change your database structure. Rename your `password` column to `old_password`.
2. During login process, check if the column `old_password` for the user is empty or not. If it is not empty, then you have to use your old hashing method to authenticate the user. Use the `old_password` column as the password for the user.
3. Once this user is logged in using the old password and the login is successful, you can make a new hash for the password and store it in the `password` column. You then remove the value in the `old_password` column. This way, you will be generating a new correct hash for the user without the user even realizing (without having him to manually reset his password).
4. Once when you think all users have reset their password, you can then remove the `old_password` column from your database table.

Another way would be to generate random passwords for all users. When they try to login it fill fail, and then they can reset their password using their email address.